# Architecture for separating domainlogic from GUI technology?

Tags: java, user-interface, architecture

We would like to implement a GUI in Java, 
which would be technology independant.

So that building a WebFrontEnd would result in implementing some additional renderers, 
without reimplementing the GUI.

Which architecture patterns should we use?

Answer (score 0):

You should start by looking at the [Model-View-Controller design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).